How to update a nested field in dynamodb via cli?
I have a record saved in dynamodb:
{
 ...
 st: {
   fs: {
      se: true
   }
  }
}

when I run the command to update st->fs->se in this record,
aws dynamodb update-item --table-name tableName --key '...' --update-expression 'SET #st.#fs.#se= :c' --expression-attribute-values '{":c": {"BOOL": false}}' --expression-attribute-values '{":c": {"BOOL": false}}'  --expression-attribute-names '{"#st": "st", "#fs":"fs", "#se": "se" }'

I got error:
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update

How can I update the nested field?

This works without issue from my side, here is the code:
TABLE_NAME='TestTable001'

aws dynamodb create-table --table-name $TABLE_NAME \
--attribute-definitions AttributeName=PK,AttributeType=S \
--key-schema AttributeName=PK,KeyType=HASH \
--provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5

aws dynamodb wait table-exists --table-name $TABLE_NAME

aws dynamodb put-item --table-name $TABLE_NAME \
--item '{
  "PK": {
    "S": "LHNNG"
  },
  "mymap": {
    "M": {
      "st": {
        "M": {
          "fs": {
            "M": {
              "se": {
                "BOOL": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

aws dynamodb update-item --table-name $TABLE_NAME \
--key '{"PK": {"S": "LHNNG"}}' \
--update-expression "SET #m.#st.#fs.#se = :c" \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#m":"mymap", "#st":"st", "#fs":"fs", "#se":"se"}' \
--expression-attribute-values '{":c":{"BOOL": false}}'

I would suggest examining the exact path of your attribute.
